# Getting changes made to record from within the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, controller

Here is something that I thought would be insanely easy, but as it turns out isn't.

I am trying to find the changes made to some record (let's call it a FooBar) in the update action of my FooBarsController.

Unfortunately it would seem that the .update method defined in ActiveRecord::Persistence, does not update the `changes` property on the record.

For Instance:

```
def update
  @resource = FooBar.find(params[:id])
  if @resource.update(resource_params)
    @resource.changes # => {} 
    render json: @resource
  else
    render_validation_errors @resource.errors
  end
end
```

Why is this? Does anyone have any idea on HOW to get the changes?

Note: I DO NOT want to use model hooks. The code I am trying to use with the changes will use the `current_user` method, therefore, using model hooks will be all kinds of dirty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it!

So there is this wonderful thing called `.previous_changes` that finds the changes made in the previous transaction, therefore relying on the update method to be called, instead of avoiding it.

With this I was able to something like:

```
def update
  @resource = FooBar.find(params[:id])
  if @resource.update(resource_params)
    @resource.previous_changes # => {'some' => 'changes', 'attribute' => 'new value'} 
    render json: @resource
  else
    render_validation_errors @resource.errors
  end
end
```

Comment: Can't accept answer for another two days, so if someone sees this thread before then or I forgot to mark it (much more likely), I'll go on record to say this works quite nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [ActiveModel::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) Module.

It has a [changed_attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html#method-i-changed_attributes.) method which will give you a hash of the attributes with unsaved changes indicating their original values

e.g.

```
person.name # => "bob"
person.name = 'robert'
person.changed_attributes # => {"name" => "bob"}
```

Also, there is a nice gem [paper_trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) which helps track changes to the models' data. That could be useful for you too! From its github page:

> Track changes to your models, for auditing or versioning. See how a
>   model looked at any stage in its lifecycle, revert it to any version,
>   or restore it after it has been destroyed.

Comment: I believe the `update` method wraps the save call in a transaction. I don't want to remove it for fear that it could break either future iterations of rails, or worse. Someone may have also have gems that might be doing monkey patching or just straight up relying on the fact that the update method will be called. If that was the case, this solution wouldn't work for them. Do these seem like valid concerns?    
  
Edit: It does, check this out https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5d1402a1011f58b405e42007d3ceed4e122d273e/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L260

Comment: Unfortunately this still wouldn't work, (assuming this is) due to the transaction wrapping the `update`. When I tried it out, I got the same empty hash as I received with the `.changes` method.

Comment: paper_trail is awesome! I totally agree, but it is a bit too much overkill for my purposes.